# how to make html drop down to be filled when page is loaded

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

**unable to load drop down when page is loaded**

i am trying to fill the html drop down when page is loaded but i am unable to achieve it.
so i tried it in click event of drop down then it is loading.
i written this code

```
function data() {
        var select = document.getElementById("year");
        for (var i = 20; i >= 10; --i) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = i;
            option.text = i + "a";
            select.add(option, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have "contentString" defined, but you are not using it. I think you are wanting to append that somewhere. Secondly, I think you mean to do this:

```
document.getElementById('year').selectedIndex = 0;
```

You can't change the length of a node list.